# DATE column values difference

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, connection

I am trying to execute a query which has a where clause on a DATE type column against an Oracle DB.

Condition reads like

```
collectTime BETWEEN TO_DATE('2014-12-14 01:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND
                    TO_DATE('2014-12-14 03:40:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Now, if I use the DriverManager getConnection method to get the connection object and execute the prepared statement, the output looks fine. That is, when I look at the returned `collectTime` column (it comes back as java.sql.Timestamp) values, I see values between the two dates I passed in - example `2014-12-14 01:09:00`.

However, if I get the connection object through a JDBC datasource (configured in Weblogic), the column values corresponding to the DATE column come back differently. Example `2014-12-13 17:09:00.0`.

I am failing to understand the cause for this difference. All the values seem to get adjusted by a specific timezone probably. Any insights as to why this could happen?

I tried to set the session timezone to UTC but that didn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, format the date to your liking. If you don't, the date will be returned using the NLS_DATE format defined in Weblogic or wherever it's being executed.

The only way to have full control of how the date is returned is to specify it in the query, e.g.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual;
```

returns

21-dec-2014

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I get the correct formatting but the value seems to change. If I use driver manager to get the connection, I get a row 0,.0092811717335474,0,.004306984591466606,2014-12-14 01:09:00.0 and if I go through the JDBC datasource route, I get 0,.0092811717335474,0,.004306984591466606,2014-12-13 17:09:00.0. The date seems to have moved back in time by 8 hrs. This happens for all the rows for a given query.

Comment: Ahh, it's not the format  you have an issue with, it's the results themselves. Might help if you post the entire query along with the table(s) definition. 

I'm guessing still it's a difference in NLS parameters between the different environments. I apologize if this is a Java issue vs a database one...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion thread that talks about setting the timezone for Weblogic: [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2176557?tstart=0).

It suggests putting the following into the setDomainEnv.cmd file, with your correct timezone offset of course.

set JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Duser.timezone="+05:30" %JAVA_PROPERTIES% %EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES%